# Property scope in Angular2 and Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, angular, fabricjs

I have some scoping issues when working with Angular2 component and Canvas (Fabric.js) . Let's say we have the following chunk of code:

/ simplified example /

```
export class SomeComponent {

    public foo: boolean;

    ngOnInit() {
        canvas.on('text:editing:entered': this.bar);
    }

    bar() {
        this.foo = true;
        console.log(this.foo); //true
    }

    @HostListener('window:keyup')
    baz() {
        console.log(this.foo); //undefined
    }
}
```

OK. Here is what I do:

1. After component is loaded I register an event on canvas object, so when entering an edit mode on IText (I use `fabric.js`) it invokes `bar` and sets `foo` to `true`,
2. Then I hit any key on the keyboard to invoke a `baz` method and to my surprise `foo` is `undefined`!

What is going on here? Any thoughts?